# Exporting Android application with ProGuard gives ParseException error

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am getting the following error when exporting Android application with Proguard (via ADT from Eclipse).

"proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '(' or separator ';' before 'name'"

I see that other ProGuard parse error problems were solved by upgrading Proguard and sdk; however, no luck here after all upgrades.  Any one seen this / solved this before? Thank you in advance for your help!

**Environment**

> ADT 22.0.1
>
> Eclipse SDK 4.2.2
>
> Android SDK 4.2, SDK Tools rev 22
>
> Proguard v4.9

**Console log**

> Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
>   proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '(' or separator ';' before
>   'name' in line 155 of file '~/project/bin/proguard.txt', included from
>   argument number 4 at
>   proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:966)
>   at
>   proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:729)
>   at
>   proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:516)
>   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:165) at
>   proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:476)

**Line 55 from project**

> -keepclassmembers class * { *** method name(...); }

**proguard.cfg**

> -optimizationpasses 5
>   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -dontpreverify
>   -verbose
>   -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
>
> -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
>       public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
>       public static int v(...);
>       public static int d(...); }
>
> -printmapping out.map
>
> -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
>   -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
>   -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
>   -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       native ; }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); }
>
> -keepclassmembers enum * {
>       public static **[] values();
>       public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }
>
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {    public void *(android.view.View);    public void *(android.view.MenuItem); }
>
> -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
>       public static ; }

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem might be :

> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * { native ; }

you could try :

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { 
    native <methods>; 
}
```